# How to get logged in user in Sripe API webhook

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, stripe-payments

I am using stripe to accept subscription payments. I have webhooks set up but I cannot save the data to my DB with the appropriate logged in user. The webhooks route is called independently so `User.Identity.GetId()` has no context and putting the `[Authorize]` attribute makes the call fail. How do I properly save the logged in user to my DB?

Here is the tutorial I was following:
https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/quickstart

My Code snippet:

```
....
                else if (stripeEvent.Type == Events.CustomerSubscriptionCreated)
                {
                    var subscription = stripeEvent.Data.Object as Subscription;

                    var id = Guid.NewGuid();
                    List<(string, object)> parameters = new List<(string, object)>()
                    {
                        ("@idadd", id.ToString()),
                        ("@useridadd", User.Identity.GetId()),
                        ("@custidadd", subscription.CustomerId),
                    };

                    SQLHelper.ExecuteNonQuery("add_payment", parameters);
                }
....
```

Answer (score 0):

In .Net `UserIdentity` in `HttpContext` is used on authenticated routes in order to identify the current `User`. `Webhook` endpoints in general, and for the integration with Stripe as well, are usually anonymous routes. So there’s no `UserIdentity` on the `HttpContext`.

Depending on what Payment Integration with Stripe you’re using, there are different ways of storing  `Metadata` on the `Subscription` object. The `Metadata` is a dictionary (key/value) where you could store custom properties such as `UserId` (you could name that however you want) which maps to `Id` of your `User` in you `db`. Once that metadata is saved, you could then retrieve it in the `webhook` endpoint.

**Use case #1:** If you’re creating your `Subscription` manually you will store the `UserId`  field to the `Metadata` parameter and retrieve it in the `webhook` endpoint.

**Use case #2:** If you’re relying on `Checkout Sessions`, in that case use `SubscriptionData.Metadata` to store it on the `Subscription` object  and retrieve it in the `webhook` endpoint.

Finally,  in your `webhook` endpoint, you then replace `User.Identity.GetId()` with `subscription.Metadata["UserId"]` in the code you posted.

Comment: How to do I map the metadata Id to my User in the DB? When the webhook event is called, there is no way for me to get my User.

Comment: To be clear, you would set the Metadata not when receiving the webhook, but when creating the Subscription in Stripe at the start of the transaction process. See my updated answer!